# The weak version of the law of large numbers clarification

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Given a series of random variables $\{X_i\}$, where $1\leq i<n$, sharing the same expectation, but different variances and not necessarily distributed the same. Is there a rule I can apply to prove the series obeys the weak version of the law of large numbers ?

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: yeah for some reason it didnt show up but now its edited..any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, even the Strong Law does not require equal variances (however, it makes to proofs much more easier). For example, see the [Kolmogorov's Strong Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) (the weak law follows from the strong law).